# Wanting a groupby that gives the max value of a column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the max value of 'OPTY_CLOSE_DATE' grouped by 'SCU_KEY' for each product. The results will populate on a new column called ['END_DATE']. Although there might be a code where you can get that number for each product without having to do 3 sets of code, we could just focus on doing it for the product 'HCM' since there are only 3 products (bonus points though if you are able to do a code that captures each product). The other products for now can be filled with NaN if needed to be specified. Not getting the right results, so let me know how I could do it right. The image of the dataframe is attached. THe right results will show for the 'END_DATE' for the first three rows (SCU_KEY = 3) would be '2020-04-15'. SCU_KEY 314 will have '2019-02-05'; SCU_KEY 315 will have '2019-02-05'; SCU_KEY 316 will ONLY have '2020-09-24' with the other 2 values prior will be NaN since the product is EPM and not HCM. My code is shown below to achieve this:

```
df_5['END_DATE'] = df_5[df_5['PRODUCT'] =='HCM'].groupby('SCU_KEY')['OPTY_CLOSE_DATE'].max()
```

[image]

Comment: it seems quite likely that df_5['END_DATE'] = df_5.groupby(['SCU_KEY','PRODUCT'])['OPTY_CLOSE_DATE'].max() will do the job for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use transform and group by both columns of interest.

```
data = np.array([
    [3,3,3,4,4,314,315,316,316,316],
    ['HCM','HCM','HCM','SCM','SCM','HCM','HCM','EPM','EPM','HCM'],
    ['2019-08-30','2019-12-09','2020-04-15','2019-02-24','2018-04-10',
    '2019-02-05','2019-09-30','2018-05-30','2018-10-04','2020-09-24']
    ])
df = pd.DataFrame(data = data.T, columns = ['scu_key', 'product', 'opty_close_date'])
df['opty_close_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['opty_close_date'])
# if you want to preserve the df as is and just add a max date column 
df['max_date'] = (
    df.groupby(['scu_key','product'])['opty_close_date'].transform('max')
)
```

Output:

```
scu_key product opty_close_date max_date
0   3   HCM 2019-08-30  2020-04-15
1   3   HCM 2019-12-09  2020-04-15
2   3   HCM 2020-04-15  2020-04-15
3   4   SCM 2019-02-24  2019-02-24
4   4   SCM 2018-04-10  2019-02-24
5   314 HCM 2019-02-05  2019-02-05
6   315 HCM 2019-09-30  2019-09-30
7   316 EPM 2018-05-30  2018-10-04
8   316 EPM 2018-10-04  2018-10-04
9   316 HCM 2020-09-24  2020-09-24
```